# O que significa "tem o corpo fechado"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

- Que significa "ter o corpo fechado"?

Inicialmente encontrei a expressão na música de capoeira Adeus Besouro:

> Lá na Bahia
> Terra de São Salvador
> Besouro era valente
> **Tinha o corpo fechado**
> Mas a traição o matou

Procurando, encontro muitos usos da expressão:

- Como título brasileiro do filme [Unbreakable](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbreakable_(filme));
- Como descrição primária de um homem, no título «[O Homem do Corpo Fechado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Homem_do_Corpo_Fechado)»;

Mas não encontro nos dicionários.

Parece indicar uma espécie de invencibilidade física, ou resistência sobrenatural.
O que significa, exatamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possui "corpo fechado" aquele que foi objeto de ritual normalmente sombrio com objetivo de tornar a pessoa impossível de ser machucada ou ferida.

"Fechar o corpo" é prática comum dos rituais religiosos de curandeirismo, frequentemente associada a cultos de origem africana, como o "vudu" e a "macumba". Significa conceder imunidade a danos físicos externos.

O termo é utilizado quase que somente no contexto de magia negra, bruxaria, ocultismo, satanismo, dificilmente sendo aplicado para magia "boa", ou "da luz" em geral. Pode-se entender como uma versão sombria da frase "O Senhor é meu pastor, e nada me faltará." (salmo 23).

> - Vou lá enfrentar o João-Grandão.
> - Mas ele vai te matar!
> - Não vai. Eu tenho *corpo fechado.*

Comment: Obrigado! Preciso apenas de um esclarecimento: *do ponto de vista dos praticantes dos cultos de origem africana*, como o vudu e a macumba, "fechar o corpo" é um ritual sombrio, coisa negativa? Como um pacto com os espíritos maus? Ou é neutra? Ou positiva? Ou pode ser qualquer uma delas?

Comment: Mas o Besouro é descrito e adorado como um capoeirista exímio; se ter o corpo fechado fosse algo sombrio e "pecaminoso", duvido que dissessem isso dele naquela música, que o descreve como valente e vítima inocente de uma traição. Tenho dificuldade em harmonizar estas duas coisas.

Comment: @ANeves Não, não é necessariamente negativo, tampouco o termo é utilizado apenas no contexto dos cultos mencionados, tendo sido há muito tempo absorvido pela cultura brasileira em geral.

Comment: Em grande parte das vezes sim, mas não necessariamente. O Besouro era capoeirista, da Bahia, estado com grande influência de tradições africanas; aonde os cultos como o candomblé não são associados a espíritos maus.

Comment: Companheiro, a tua resposta agrada-me muito no geral, mas acho que perde qualidade com o terceiro parágrafo e a conotação negativa que associas ao ritual.

Comment: Vudu, não. No Brasil, candomblé ou macumba.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo o [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corpo_fechado):

> (*of a person, chiefly in supernatural or superstitous context*) The characteristic of being virtually or completely impervious to any harm.

E ainda segundo o Aulete, no [verbete secundário de corpo](http://aulete.com.br/corpo):

> Corpo fechado
>
> 1. Segundo certas crenças, corpo invulnerável a doenças e outros males, por ter proteção sobrenatural.

Answer (score 1):

Ter "corpo fechado" significa gozar de algum tipo de proteção mística contra doenças, ferimentos, etc.

O termo provavelmente [tem origem](https://pt.globalvoices.org/2016/08/06/um-ritual-de-protecao-para-fechar-o-corpo-liga-tradicoes-religiosas-diferentes-no-brasil/) em religiões de matriz africana, como o candomblé e a umbanda, mas há pelo menos um século faz parte da cultura como um todo do país. Já o conceito genérico de proteção mística/divina é certamente pré-histórico.

Essa proteção seria conferida por meio de amuletos e/ou rituais que, a depender da crença, variam desde simples orações (como [fazia Lampião](https://seer.ufs.br/index.php/pontadelanca/article/view/9295) - criminoso conhecido do início do século XX) até [sacrifícios humanos](https://www.bol.uol.com.br/noticias/2015/01/20/trio-e-condenado-por-morte-de-jovem-em-ritual-de-magia-negra-em-mg.htm), passando pelo consumo ritualizado de [bebidas alcoólicas](http://g1.globo.com/jornalhoje/0,,MUL1131761-16022,00-CORPO+FECHADO.html).

Answer (score 1):

Há muito tempo que o termo "corpo fechado" deixou de ser falado exclusivamente pelos adeptos de religiões trazidas da África ou criadas já em solo brasileiro por afro-descendentes. É usado por muitos brasileiros do nordeste e do sudeste, geralmente com um dos significados abaixo, sem que o interlocutor tenha sido submetido a qualquer ritual de magia negra, seja ele ou não praticante de alguma religião. Geralmente é resposta dada a alguma ameaça.

- "Comigo não vai acontecer."
- "Não adianta me desejar o mal, porque eu sou imune a essas coisas."
- "Tenho um anjo da guarda sempre presente."
- "Meu santo é forte e pragas não me atingem."

Answer (score -3):

Fechar o corpo é invocar um espírito poderoso que não deixe que outros espíritos entrem na pessoa, principalmente os espíritos que por ventura tenham importunado alguém. "Sabeis que o corpo é templo do espírito de Deus". Pois assim sendo, quando uma casa está vazia, ela fica aberta e desprotegida. "Cabe ao homem morrer uma só vez, e depois virá o julgamento final". Espíritos de pessoas que já morreram não têm o poder de possuir outras pessoas, inclusive as que estão vivas. O único espírito de luz é o espírito santo de Deus. "Não se surpreendam quando virem essas coisas, pois até mesmo o Diabo se apresenta como espírito de luz".

Comment: Obrigado pelo teu esforço de contribuição, Diogo, mas creio que a tua resposta se perde um pouco nas tuas opiniões religiosas. Acho que a podias melhorar muito se a expusesses num tom neutro, como se fosses um observador externo imparcial a religiões - tanto às abrahâmicas como às de origem africana.